# MongoDB: Using $inc in update statement

Tags: mongodb

I have a Collection in mongoDB with many documents one of which looks like:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("525c22348771ebd7b179add8"),
"clear" : "YES",
"cust_id" : "A1234",
"score" : 500,
"status" : "A"
}
```

I have written a mongo Shell code to get the cust_id and sum of score of all the cust_id whose status is "A"

```
cust_to_clear=db.aggregation.aggregate(
    {$match:{status:'A'}},
    {$group:{_id:'$cust_id',total:{$sum:'$score'}}})
```

The Above code gives me a result as follow:

```
{
"result" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : "A4567",
        "total" : 600
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : "A3456",
        "total" : 1400
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : "A2345",
        "total" : 301
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : "A1234",
        "total" : 800
    }
],
"ok" : 1
}
```

My requirement is to update the score of all the cust_id's fetched from the result above to score+100.
Please suggest me how do I code the requirement in mongo Shell?

My Approach:

```
cust_to_clear.result.forEach(
    function(x){
     db.aggregation.update({cust_id:x._id},{$set:{score:{$inc:{$score:100}}}}, {multi: true})}
     )
```

Expected Output:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("525c22348771ebd7b179add8"),
"clear" : "YES",
"cust_id" : "A1234",
"score" : 600,
"status" : "A"
}
```

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: You want to upload the elements which resulted in aggregation framework operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.aggregation.update({ cust_id : x._id }, { $inc : { 'score' : 100 }}, {multi: true});
```